# Forecast Daily Data with Multiple Seasonality

Tags: time-series, modeling, multiple-seasonalities

I am new to the field of time series forecast and trying to build a time series model on R for a daily data, which I think there are multiple seasonality, weekly and monthly.

My data contain the number of customers collected from a store operating on weekdays. So data are only collected from Monday through Friday.  Also, there are holidays.

How do you deal with holiday ?

Could you please give me suggestion what model I should use ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this paper maybe:
[Gould, P. G., Koehler, A. B., Ord, J. K., Snyder, R. D., Hyndman, R. J., & Vahid-Araghi, F. (2008). Forecasting time series with multiple seasonal patterns. European Journal of Operational Research, 191(1), 207–222.](http://www.buseco.monash.edu.au/ebs/pubs/wpapers/2004/wp28-04.pdf)